How to use already existing bolts width to hang a floating shelf that has holes of different spacing?
There are two bolts in our concrete wall that we cannot remove. Is there some device that can hang on these bolts to either pseudo-extend the width (the space between the bolts) or lessen it? Does such a thing exist? This is for mounting a floating shelf. The shelf comes with a mounting bracket that has holes of different spacing from that on my wall…

A pic and far more info on what you are attempting to do is needed here.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

+1 to pics. Maybe you can drill holes in the new shelf bracket to conform to your existing bolts.

Yes, make a bracket that bolts to the wall with the existing bolts.
Depending on the distance between the existing bolts, the fixing points of the new item (shelf) and the envisaged load, the bracket may need to be thicker or if metal shaped to give strength.

The bracket can be wood or metal depending on other factors.
Another option is to cut the existing bolts back to the surface and then drill new holes to match the new shelf.
The consideration then becomes:

will the old holes / bolts need hiding?

will the new holes be too close to the old holes? As the wall material strength affects the load capacity.



This can be difficult to fit behind a floating shelf in a neat way. Otherwise a solid idea.

@jpa many varied wall materials make using floating shelves difficult...

If cutting back, one probably only needs to cut a single existing bolt, not both.

@MikeB that is, of course, assuming that one of those existing bolts is sufficiently well placed...
